# Difficulty transferring data in struct from kernel space to user space

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, system-calls

I am trying to write a system call that can get information about a process in Linux:

my system call prototype is : `long pid_info(struct info *info, int pid)`

I have the following struct :

```
struct info {
        int pid;
        char cwd[4096];
        char root[4096];
}
```

and in my system call, I have the following code :

```
SYSCALL_DEFINE2(pid_info, struct info *, info, int, pid)
{
        ...
        int err;
        char *path_root;

        ...
        // After getting the root path
        err = copy_to_user(info->root, path_root, 
                    strlen(path_root) + 1);
        if (err)
                return -EFAULT;
        // Just to check if it copied to info->root (and later when i run dmesg it prints the path).
        pr_info("Root path (user) : %s\n", info->root);
        ...

        return (0);
}
```

My main to test the system call :

```
int main(void)
{
        struct info info;
        int ret;

        ret = syscall(355, &info, 190);
        if (ret == -1)
                return 0;
        //This print nothing even though the dmesg log says it was copied.
        printf("Path : %s\n", info->root);
        return (0);
}
```

Somehow the data that i copied across disappear and am struggling in finding out why, since copy_to_user should transfer the data from kernel space to user space.

Comment: Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out will change it now

Comment: Not the actual problem, but you seem to copy one byte too little ... `strlen()` *doesn't* count the terminating 0 byte.

Comment: @FelixPalmen thanks for pointing that out

Comment: Maybe try creating a [mcve] here, so people can test themselves. If you create a simple syscall that just copies from a string constant to a user-supplied `char *` buffer, do you run into the same problem?

Comment: when i pass a char pointer with dynamically allocated memory, the path is copied to user space but if i put the same char pointer in struct it does not copy it to user space

Comment: and when you do something as simple as `char buf[1024]; ret = syscall(355, &buf);`?

Comment: @FelixPalmen I tried that and the path is returned without any problems. But if i put the variable in a struct it does not return the path.

Comment: Ok, without any own experience with Linux: I was instantly surprised by `pr_info("Root path (user) : %s\n", info->root);` working if `info->root` is indeed a userspace pointer. My guess is the dereferencing of the userspace pointer `info` doesn't work as you expect. If that's really the reason, copying the struct to kernelspace first, filling it there and then copying it back should work.

Comment: @FelixPalmen I tried that just now and am still experiencing the same problem as before.